# Python print string with unicode escape characters

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to print the literal unicode escape character of "Pedro Le\u00F3n". When I do the following:

```
test = "Pedro Le\u00F3n"
print(test)

>>> Pedro León
```

How can I get it to output "Pedro Le\u00F3n"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use raw strings. Simply use `r` before your string:

```
test = r"Pedro Le\\u00F3n"
print(test)
```

Output: `Pedro Le\\u00F3n`

Comment: Why did you put a double-backslash?

Answer (score 2):

Encode to bytes with the `unicode_escape` [encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html?highlight=codecs#text-encodings), and decode right back:

```
>>> out = test.encode('unicode_escape').decode()
>>> out
'Pedro Le\\xf3n'
>>> print(out)
Pedro Le\xf3n
```

Note that it's a `\xXX` escape instead of a `\uXXXX` escape, since it's less than U+FF. For comparison:

```
>>> '\u0080'
'\x80'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
test = "Pedro Le\\u00F3n"
print(test)
```

it causes because in python there are many "special characters like" '\n' and more and if you want to ignore it you need to write \ \ instead of \